# In the 'gam' package for R, what is the difference in purpose between the formulas supplied to gam and step.gam functions?

Tags: r, gam

Trying to use `gam::step.gam` to build a model.  Don't understand why that function asks for a formula if the input model object already has an embedded formula (from when it was fit via `gam::gam`)

Why ask for the formula twice?  When would I want to use different formulas between the two functions?

My review of `help("gam")` and `help("step.gam")` didn't uncover anything to explain why I'd use one formula when first fitting model with `gam` and another when feeding that model to `step.gam`.

Comment: Have you studied `help("step.gam")`?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Questions that are solely about programming is [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site and may be closed.  If you have a statistical question, please edit your post to emphasize it.  Programming questions may be better received at StackOverflow (do *not* cross-post there, ask the moderators to migrate it) or you can browse the [list of internet support for statistics software](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) that we maintain.

Comment: This is not a question about how GAMs work, but how the `R` functions work. This is a question about using `R` code, not about statistics. If you want to know why the package developers designed the functions the way they did, you should ask them. This is off topic here.

Comment: Migrating to SO per request of OP.